# Error “Media type 'application/json' is not supported” Api GMAIL

Tags: php, api, curl, postman, gmail-api

I am doing an exercise to learn how to use the GMAIL api, as an example I am trying to send a message by mail, but it sends me the following error "Media type 'application / json' is not supported". Could you support me to track down the bug and be able to fix it?

> Postman configuration.

[image]

> GMAIL api link.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/send

Greetings and excellent Friday

Answer (score 0):

### Your [message ressource](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#Message) must be a base64url encoded string

For testing purposes, you can use any online base64url encoder and than assign the encoded string to `"raw"` with the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/send).

Once you get the request right, it will be easier for you to transfer it into your specific environment.

Answer (score 0):

1.)In Header Tab just place

content-Type : message/rfc822

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58HOG.png)

2.)In body Tab(Request body content type "raw" and format "text")  :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvGVG.png)